# C - Scanning a dynamic 2D array of chars and allocation

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc

I would like to have a dynamic 2D array of chars, max 200 and scan to it.
I am not really sure how to do this, all I came up with is to define the dynamic arrays (and I don't even know if it is right):

```
char **arr = (char **)malloc( (len+1) * sizeof(char*) );
  for (i=0;  (len+1)>0; i++)
    char *arr1 = (char *) malloc ( (len+1) * sizeof(char) );
```

But I am not sure what to put in the (len) - let's say I would like an array of 51x150, depending on the scanned input. 
How to allocate the array based on the scanned value and print it?

An example of input:

```
####.#...##
##.##.#.###
##.###.#.##
#.##.##.#..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a real 2D array and not a segmented look-up table.

```
size_t x = 51;  // user input
size_t y = 150; // user input

char (*arr)[y] = malloc( sizeof(char[x][y]) );
...
arr[i][j] = something;
...
free(arr);
```

This is much faster and safer than a segmented look-up table. This also allows you to `memcpy` data in and out of the array, even if that data is larger than one line.

Comment: I need to define the size of the arrays depending on the size of the input. therefore for the example that I have provided, the array would be allocated as
size_t x=11;
size_t y=4;

Comment: @Darxor Yes, that's what this code does. Simply replace the assignments to x and y with scanf, fgets or whatever.